# Classifying sets into arithmetic hierarchy

Tags: logic, computability

I am given the sets $A$ such that $|A|<\infty, A\neq\emptyset$ and $B$ such that $|B|=\infty$. I am then supposed to find where the following sets go in the arithmetic hierarchy:

$S=\{e\colon \text{dom}(\Phi_e)=A\}$

$T=\{e\colon \text{dom}(\Phi_e)=B\}$

but am a bit confused on how to decide this? It is clear they are not in $\Sigma_1,\Pi_1$ but I don't know where to go from there and why their classifications may be different, since as far as I can see any logical statement for one set would also work for the other? Thanks!

Note: $\Phi_e$ denotes the $e$-th partial computable function.

Comment: What is $\Phi_e$?

Comment: Ah right. $\Phi_e$ denotes the $e$-th partial computable function.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include more context, such as the source of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\psi$ be a primitive recursive function such that  $\psi(e,n,t)=1$ if $\Phi_e(n)$ halts in $t$ steps or less otherwise $\psi(e,n,t)=0$.

Then $S=\{n\;|\;\exists t\forall x \forall u(u\ge t \wedge x\in A\Leftrightarrow\psi(n,x,u)=1)\}$, so $S\in\Sigma_2$.

But also $S=\{n\;|\;\forall x \forall u\exists t(u\ge t \wedge x\in A\Leftrightarrow\psi(n,x,u)=1)\}$, so $S\in\Pi_2$.

So $S\in\Delta_2$. Note that $S\notin\Sigma_1\cup\Pi_1$

Note that $x\in A$ is a recursive primitive relation as $A$ is finite.

If $B$ is not recursively enumerable, then $T$ is empty, so $T\in\Delta_0$.

If $B$ is recursively enumerable, let $b$ such that $B=dom(\Phi_b)$.

Then $T=\{n\;|\;\forall x\forall u\exists t \quad u>t\Rightarrow (\psi(b,x,u)=1\Leftrightarrow\psi(n,x,u)=1)\}$. So $T\in\Pi_2$.

The main difference is that as $A$ is finite, there is time $t$ such that if a function $f$ of domain $A$ is computed, either $f$ halts before time $t$ or never halts (you can see $t$ as the maximum time needed to converge). But $B$ is infinite, so there may be no maximum time over all entries, so $T\notin \Sigma_2$

Comment: @CarlMummert you're right, I added a $u$ to avoid that !

Comment: That does fix the argument, although $S$ is actually in $\Delta^0_2$ and $T$ is $\Sigma^0_2$. If $B = W_j$ then we want $\{e : W_e = W_j\}$, and equality between two r.e. sets is $\Pi^0_2$.

Comment: @CarlMummert Should be ok now. However to formally show that $T\notin\Sigma_2$ I feel that some proof by contradiction would be necessary...

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. The set of $i$ such that $W_i = \mathbb{N}$ is $\Pi^0_2$ complete: given a formula $(\forall p)(\exists q) \psi(p,q,n)$ where $\psi$ has only bounded quantifiers, we can make a program that, given $p$, halts if and only if it finds a $q$, so this program has domain $\mathbb{N}$ if and only if the formula is true. So, if we let $B = \mathbb{N}$ then the corresponding set $T$ cannot be $\Sigma^0_2$ because the set of true $\Pi^0_2$ formulas is not $\Sigma^0_2$.